# TYPO3 6.2 content frames section_frame

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I've used TYPO3 content frames in earlier versions of TYPO3 (4.5, 4.7) and everything worked. No problems. Never!

Now with TYPO3 6.2.x my section_frames (content frames) didn't work anymore?! Where's the problem? I cleared cache etc ..

Here is my pageTS

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
section_frame {
# remove all frames
removeItems = 1,5,6,10,11,12,20,21,66

# add new frame
addItems.101 = Blue box
addItems.102 = No Wrapper
  }
}
```

and here is my setup.ts

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {

key.field = section_frame

101 < .default
101.wrap = <div class="teaser-column">|</div>

102.wrap = <div class="teaser-column">|</div>
102.20.10.value = csc-default row-distance-top
}
```

I have no idea .. It doesn't work.

At my backend, I see the two Frames "Blue Box" and "No Wrapper", but there is no effect in Frontend?!

Comment: DAmn, there was sth. like that in my setup.ts - that's the problem


tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the static ts was changed !!!

take a look is the : EXT:css_styled_content/static/

now you have to use:

```
102.30.cObject.default.value = ><div class="teaser-column">|</div></div>
```

instead of your way

```
102.wrap = <div class="teaser-column">|</div>
102.20.10.value = csc-default row-distance-top
```

Comment: Thanks. 
`tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  key.field = section_frame
  100 < .default
  100.wrap = <div class="aaaaaaaaaaa">|</div>
  100.20.10.value = csc-frame csc-frame-ruler
}`